# Is it necessary to escape slashes in strings in Windows Registry?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

This is a question mostly concerning WinAPI RegSetValueEx. If you look at its description in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'd find:

> lpData [in] The data to be stored.
>
> REG_SZ, the string must be null-terminated. With the REG_MULTI_SZ data
>   type, the string must be terminated with two null characters. A
>   backslash must be preceded by another backslash as an escape
>   character. For example, specify "C:\\mydir\\myfile" to store the
>   string "C:\mydir\myfile".

The question I have, do I really need to escape slashes? Because I've never done that before and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: The escaping is for C++, not for the method.  So, for example, if you were going to take user input off of the command line, you would not need to transform the text to have \\ for all of the \.  If, however, you were going to use a string literal in the code, like "C:\..." you would need your C++ source to have "C:\\...".  I'm assuming that this is what the docs are talking about.  There's a chance the page means you would actually need to do "C:\\\\..." (in which case you could have to transform user input)

Comment: @Corbin :) Well, that makes a big difference. It's very confusing how they put it in the documentation.

Comment: +1 good question, this documentation is really bizarre

Comment: If I had to guess, I would assume it means you must actually pass it \\, not you must use \\ in source code to represent a single slash.  Just insert an entry with "\\\\" and see if it comes out as "\\" or "\".  If it comes out as "\", then you must actually escape the slashes, whereas if it comes out as "\\", it was simply reminding people that \ is a special character in C++ and must be escaped.  I feel like that documentation could be significantly improved with some clarity... lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is indeed a documentation error. You do not need to escape backslashes here. The exact string that you send to this API is what will be stored in the registry. No processing of backslashes will be performed.

Now, it's true that in C and C++ you need to escape certain characters in string literals, but that's not pertinent to a Win32 API documentation. That's an issue for source code to object code translation for specific languages and quite beyond the remit of this documentation.

Comment: Indeed.  The key part is escaping backslash characters in *string literals*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because `\` has a meaning in C++, whereas `\\` means an ordinary backslash.

When `\` appears in a string, C++ compiler will look at the next character and convert the combination into something (for example `\n` will be converted into a "newline" character). `\\` will be converted into a regular backslash. This is called "escaping" (historically, on old terminals, the ESC+key combination was used for many keys that were not on the keyboard).

Comment: This is not C++. I'm talking about the value that is passed to RegSetValueEx API.

Comment: @ahmd0 You tagged your question with C++. What language are you using then?

Comment: Yes, C++. And of course I know that one needs to escape things with a slash in C. They put it into a description for a Windows API though that has no relation to C++ or any other language. Again, I want to know if MS wants us to escape strings that are passed to registry APIs.

Comment: @littleadv ahmd0 is right, the MSDN page doesn't mention languages. The way that page is written is totally confusing.

Comment: @ahmd0 Windows API for what language? The link you provided is the C API, C has the same escaping rules.

Comment: @MrLister I don't know what other languages allow native access to WINAPI, but the page is using clearly C syntax.

Comment: @littleadv Your statement is totally wrong. I can use VB or C#, or pure ASM or any other language to invoke those APIs. There should be no connection to a programming language there. So, the bottom line, guys, one does not need to escape slashes (in memory) strings, correct?

Comment: @ahmd0 of course not. This is clearly a C interface, how can you confuse it for VB or assembly?

Comment: @ahmd0 I have never put double backslashes in the registry. And I'm not about to start!

Comment: @ahmd0 BTW: If you *do* put double backslashes - it *will* still work just fine.

Comment: @littleadv If this is just about C, why does the page only mention backslashes and not quotes and other characters that need escaping in C?

Comment: OK. It's just strange that MS decided to teach us C escaping rules in a WinAPI parameter description. That's it. Thanks.

Comment: @MrLister because backslashes you must use - they force it on you. At least that's what I think as to why, I didn't write that page.

Comment: @ahmd0 yes, I agree, but then again - what do you expect from MS? That's a common bug, so they probably thought its worth mentioning. I don't think it occurred to them that someone might mistake that API syntax for VB....

Comment: You're calling this API function THROUGH C++, so it obviously has something to do with C++. If you look at the VB version of this function you'll see no \\. Think of it that way: If you have a car you have to use the right key, even though every car does the same in principle. You can't just say "ah I only want to start the engine, what do I care about the car", but you can only start the engine THROUGH the specific car you're sitting in.

Comment: @s3rius The documentation is generic because the API is language neutral. The cars aren't helping.